# Ad click prediction with very unbalanced data

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

I have some very unbalanced data(3% positive), and I am using xgboost to do some learning. The file is pretty big, and I previously tried logistic regression, randomforest and svm(using only some subsample of the whole data, because the data is too big). To account for data unbalance, I tried class weight and balancing data using SMOTE(which makes the data super big). But none of this seems to help. The accuracy rate gets worse when I use either of the above mention approach.

When I tried xgboost and try to tune scale-positive-weight parameter like the document suggested, it only makes accuracy worse. Overall, all my models works worse than just predicting all 0s.

Is there anyway I can account this data imbalance?

here's my code for xgboost

```
x = data[:,3:] 
y = data[:,2]
from xgboost import XGBClassifier 
model = XGBClassifier(scale_pos_weight = np.sum(y==0)/np.sum(y==1))
model.fit(x, y, eval_metric="auc")
# make predictions for test data
y_pred = model.predict(x)
#predictions = [round(value) for value in y_pred]
# evaluate predictions
accuracy = accuracy_score(y, y_pred)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (accuracy * 100.0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems most of the advice online to handle imbalanced data with XGBoost (and otherwise) is to do a hyperparameter tuning by search.

You may use scikit-learn's `GridSearchCV`: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html

But, nowadays there are better methods than a grid-search to explore the paramteric space, e.g. scikit-optimize: https://scikit-optimize.github.io/#skopt.BayesSearchCV

Example: (this is a regressor, bit works just the same for classification

```
from xgboost import XGBRegressor
from skopt import BayesSearchCV

n_features = X_train.shape[1] - 1

sum_pos = np.sum(y_train==1)
sum_neg = np.sum(y_train==0)

opt = BayesSearchCV(
    XGBRegressor(objective='reg:linear', n_jobs=4, scale_pos_weight = sum_neg/sum_pos),
    {
        'n_estimators': (1, 50),
        'max_depth': (1, 20),
        'learning_rate': (10**-5, 10**0, "log-uniform"),
        'min_child_weight': (1, 5),
        'max_delta_step': (1, 10)
    },
    n_iter=8, # may want to have more iterations here... :)
    verbose=99
)

opt.fit(X_train[:,1:], y_train)
```